# Backpack Laravel -> Users, Inscriptions and Fairs

Tags: laravel-backpack

In Laravel Backpack.

I have 3 Models: Fair, Inscription, User

I have Fairs that celebrates every month.

I have Inscriptions of Companies to that are associated to that Fair

Each inscription has an associated User (also a Fair)

I wanted that in the List page the user can only see their Inscriptions, not all the inscriptions in all fairs

I wanted the user to see the list of the inscriptions to the fairs associated to them only

And so... also that they cannot see/modify other inscriptions associated to other users

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to customize the query on the ListOperation - https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-list-entries#custom-query-1

Please note that WHERE you customize the query is important:

- customize it in `setupListOperation()` and it will apply to that operation only;
- customize it in `setup()` and it will apply to all operations;